# $f(x) = x + \int_{0}^{1} (xy^2 + x^2y) f(y)dy$. Find $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, functional-equations

$f(x) = x + \int_{0}^{1} (xy^2 + x^2y) f(y) dy$. Find $f(x)$

I've tried taking $\int_{0}^{1} (xy^2 + x^2y) f(y) dy$ to be $k(x)$ since it comes out to be a function of $x$. That transforms our equation to $f(x) = x + k(x)$.

$f(y) = y + k(y) \implies (xy^2 + x^2y)f(y) = (xy^2 + x^2y)y + (xy^2 + x^2y)k(y)$
Now I tried integrating on both sides against $dy$ from $0$ to $1$ in an attempt to find $k(x)$

$\int_{0}^{1} (xy^2 + x^2y)f(y).dy = k(x) = \int_{0}^{1} ((xy^2 + x^2y)y + (xy^2 + x^2y)k(y)).dy$

But I got stuck trying to integrate the right hand side. Any solutions or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f(x)=x+\int_{0}^{1}[xy^2+x^2y]f(y)dy$ where $x$ and$y$ are independent variable.Find $f(x).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404981/if-fx-x-int-01xy2x2yfydy-where-x-andy-are-independent-varia) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x)%20%3D%20x%20%2B%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20(xy%5E2%20%2B%20x%5E2y)%20f(y)%20dy%24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write you equation under the form :

$$f(x) = x + x \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} y^2 f(y) dy}_b+ x^2 \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}y f(y) dy}_a\tag{1}$$

which mean that

$$f(x)=ax^2+(b+1)x \tag{2}$$

with

$$a=\int_{0}^{1}y f(y) dy \ \ (i) \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \  \ \ b=\int_{0}^{1}y^2 f(y) dy \ \ (ii)\tag{3}$$

is (at most) a second degree polynomial in variable $x$.

It suffices now to plug (2) into (3)(i) and (3)(ii) to get 2 equations in the 2 unknowns $a$ and $b$.

Up to you for the final step.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = x + \int_{0}^{1} (xy^2 + x^2y) f(y) dy$$
$$f'(x) = 1 + \int_{0}^{1} (y^2 + 2xy) f(y) dy$$
$$f''(x) = \int_{0}^{1} 2y f(y) dy=\text{constant}$$
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$ax^2+bx+c=x+ \int_{0}^{1} (xy^2 + x^2y) (ay^2+by+c) dy$$
After calculus of the integral and simplification :
$$(-\frac13 a+\frac13 b+\frac12 c)x^2+(1+\frac15 a-\frac34 b+\frac13 c)x-c=0$$
$$\begin{cases}
-\frac13 a+\frac13 b+\frac12 c=0 \\
1+\frac15 a-\frac34 b+\frac13 c=0 \\
c=0
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
a=\frac{80}{119} \\
b=\frac{180}{119}
\end{cases}$$
$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac{80}{119}x^2+\frac{180}{119}x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\int_0^{1} y^{2}f(y)dy$ and $B=\int_0^{1} yf(y)dy$. Then $f(x)=x+xA+x^{2}B$. Multiply by $x$ and integrate to get $B=\frac 1 3 +\frac A 3 +\frac  1 4 B$. Similarly multiply by $x^{2}$ and integrate to get $A=\frac 1 4 +\frac A 4 +\frac  1 5 B$. Solve these two equations for $A$ and $B$.